# Converting an Objective-C block to Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

Objective-C block:

```
[networHandler composeRequestWithMethod:MethodRespondToAppointMent
                                        paramas:queryParams        //NSDictionary
                                   onComplition:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *response){
    //                                   NSLog(@"Dict: %@", response);
    }];
```

Now I want to represent this in Swift. How should I do it?

**UPDATE:**

```
let handler = NetworkHandler.sharedInstance() as! NetworkHandler
        let dict = ["":""]

        handler.composeRequestWithMethod("", paramas: dict) { (success, response) -> Void in

        }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: `I want to write this in swift` Please show what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: let handler = NetworkHandler.sharedInstance() as! NetworkHandler
        let dict:NSDictionary!
        handler.composeRequestWithMethod("", paramas: dict, onComplition: {(success: Bool, response: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Void in
        })    }

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, if the trailing argument is a closure you can also use a shortened version of Anbu.Karthik's answer:

```
networHandler.composeRequestWithMethod(MethodRespondToAppointMent, paramas: queryParams) { success, response in
//      NSLog(@"Dict: %@", response)
}
```